# Как получить часть DataFrame по элементу мультииндекса?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть `df`, сгруппированный с использованием мультииндекса (применен метод `.groupby` по двум столбцам).

Выполняю:

```
df_by_month_group.index.levels
```

Получаю:

```
FrozenList([[9, 10, 11], ['one', 'two', 'three']])
```

Таким образом, могу получить доступ к первой части этого списка:

```
df_by_month_group.index.levels[0]
```

Получаю:

```
Int64Index([9, 10, 11], dtype='int64', name='month')
```

Выполняю цикл:

```
for i in df_by_month_group.index.levels[0]:
    print(i)
```

Ожидаемо получаю:

```
9
10
11
```

А вот iloc для этого DataFrame не работает:

```
df_by_month_group.iloc[df_by_month_group.index.levels[0]==9]
```

```
IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 3 instead of 159
```

Как поправить?

Мне нужно обрезать мой исходный DataFrame таким образом, чтобы остались только значения, у которых в мультииндексе первым элементом стоит 9.

---

UPD:
воспроизводимый результат:

```
first = [9,9,9,10,10,10]
second = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three']
third = [10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 50]
test = pd.DataFrame(zip(first, second, third), columns=['mon', 'name', 'val'])
test_gr = test.groupby(['mon', 'name']).sum()
test_gr
```

Comment: Я решил, что это тривиальная задача - iloc для мультииндекса. Что ж, попробую добавить df, спасибо.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_gr.loc[test_gr.index.get_level_values(0)==9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1:

```
In [113]: test_gr.loc[pd.IndexSlice[9, :], :]
Out[113]: 
           val
mon name      
9   one     10
    three   30
    two     20
```

Вариант 2:

```
In [114]: test_gr.query("mon == 9")
Out[114]: 
           val
mon name      
9   one     10
    three   30
    two     20
```